# objective-c to PHP websafe encoding; uuencode?

Tags: php, objective-c, base64, uuencode

I am sending strings from my objective-c app to a PHP script over HTTP.  I need to websafe these strings.

I am currently encoding with Google Toolbox for Mac **GTMStringEncoding rfc4648Base64WebsafeStringEncoding** and decoding with **base64_decode()** on the PHP end.  Works great 99% of the time.

Unfortunately, this encoding is not entirely websafe as it includes some web-interpreted characters ("/" and "-").  The regular **GTMStringEncoding rfc4648Base64StringEncoding** also includes web-interpreted characters.

Is uuencoding the data the way to go?  I see that PHP already has uudecode support, will I have top roll my own on the objective-c side?

If not uuencode, then what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems that PHP did not default support Section 5 of RFC 4648, "Base 64 Encoding with URL and Filename Safe Alphabet."  This function allows PHP to handle the 4 out-lier chars before base64_decode:

```
function base64url_decode($base64url) {
    $base64 = strtr($base64url, '-_', '+/');
    $plainText = base64_decode($base64);
    return ($plainText);
}
```

[My thanks to the anonymous "Tom" who posted it on PHP.net 6 years ago](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php#71583).